# Calculate voltage across LED

Tags: circuits

For this circuit, how to calculate the voltage across the LED when the potentiometer is turned please?

[image]

Is there a formula for this please?

Battery: 6 V,
Resistor: 200 ohms,
Potentiometer: 250 ohm

How do you iterate please as suggested in answers?

Comment: The LED is still a diode, so large part of its forward characteristics is exponential. So you iether need to know (and provide here) it data sheet, or at least its saturation current $I_s$, i.e. $I(V) = I_s \cdot e^{(\frac{V}{vt})}$.

Answer (score 1):

**The naive way:**

Subtract the nominal forward voltage of the LED from the supply voltage, and then use V/R = I

**The accurate way:**

Notice that the LED voltage drop is actually a non-linear function, not a constant.

[image: LED forward current vs forward voltage graph]

Note: This graph will be slightly different for every diode,  especially different colors.

Either approximate the function (exponential?). Or iterate, like tiger guy suggests. Or guess and check.

Answer (score 0):

You need to estimate the LED's resistance (LED's do not have linear resistance versus voltage, so use the spec sheet), add that resistance to the total and then use V=IR to determine the circuit's current.  Then use the spec sheet to determine the voltage drop).  You might need to do this iteratively, closing in on actual resistance according to the spec sheet.

Comment: This is not a good way to analyze the circuit. The "resistance" of an LED is just the derivative of its current/voltage curve at some particular value of forward voltage. That "resistance" can not be used to find the voltage across the LED at any other value of forward voltage.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, this solution does not use the resistance of the diode to calculate the voltage drop.  It takes the total current and then you use the chart.